# facing issue with filestore persistent volume in gke

Tags: yaml, disk, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using google filestore for persistent volume in kubernetes. But it is mounting only the root folder not its contents.

I am using GKE service and perform the following tasks:

volume-create:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: volume1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: x.x.x.x
    path: /share
```

Persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: volume1-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: volume1
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: image1
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: image1
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: volume1-claim
      containers:
      - name: image1
        image: gcr.io/project-gcr/image:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume
          mountPath: "/app/data"
```

But it mounting empty folder app/data not its contents. I also referred the below URL:
https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to mount an already existing persistent disk?

If so, you will need to define the disk in your configuration file.

You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd).

What kind of data is located on  /app/data , is it on a VM? Can you give me some more information on your deployment? How are you testing viewing your data?

The more details I have, the more specific we can be with the help we can provide.